# Interactive Equation editor with Latex syntax

Tags: math-software

I was using the built in equation editor used by Pearson's "MyLab and Mastering" physics course, and I really like how it's both interactive and uses Latex syntax to insert equation elements. Screenshots are shown below:

[image]

look what happens when I complete the "\sqrt"

[image]

The Latex syntax works for greek letters, superscript, etc., and makes it easy to add equation elements without having to click through a dropdown list (though it still provides one for convenience). The interactive editor view is easier to understand than pure Latex, removes the hassle of trying to match all those brackets when writing Latex, and also makes it easier to edit equations afterwards. For example:

[image]

I can hit backspace once to delete the whole thing! Compare that to the Latex equivalent

`\frac{\sqrt{\alpha^{2t}}{1-\ln{(\beta_{o})}}`

which takes 44 backspaces :O

Anyways, I guess the question is, is there an online equivalent? This is by far the fastest equation editor I've used, but the only thing this editor lacks is Latex export, which renders it useless for anything besides submitting answers to my physics homework :(

Comment: Several online-based Latex tools are periodically advertised at this site. You may find them among others at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/ads/display/11920 - please have a look, maybe that is something you may find useful. I used WriteLatex on a couple of occasions (because my collaborator used it).

Comment: I have tried all those referenced, and none of them provide the functionality of Pearson's little built-in editor :O

Comment: Thanks for letting know. It might be helpful to ask this at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

I happened across a good WYSIWYG online equations editor that uses Latex syntax and Latex export:

http://www.mathjq.com/math-editor/

[image: preview]

I actually like it even better than the Pearson equation editor :D

### UPDATE:

Looks like mathjq is dead :( However, the [mathjax docs](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/List-of-web-based-math-editors) lists a lot of alternatives. My favorites are:

#### [MathQuill](http://mathquill.com/)

Open-source editor that works the same way as mathjq. Embeddable in your own website!
[image: MathQuill Screenshot]

#### [Guppy](https://daniel3735928559.github.io/guppy/)

Works the same as mathjq and MathQuill

[image: Guppy Screenshot]

#### [myscript](http://webdemo.myscript.com/views/math.html#/demo/equation)

Converts handwritten equations to latex!!
[image: myscript screenshot]

There are also a few that are click-based with a giant list of mathematical symbols and operators to choose from, like [iMathEQ](http://www.imatheq.com/imatheq/com/imatheq/math-equation-editor-latex-mathml.html) and [camdenre's editor](http://camdenre.github.io/src/app/html/EquationEditor).

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: aw man :( i added a few alternatives, thanks for letting me know!